# "Errors occurred while updating the change sets for SVNStatusSubscriber" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I keep getting this error in Eclipse.  I uninstalled Subclipse and related packages since I just want to use Tortoise.  There are no SVN packages remaining. I cleaned my workspace and rebooted, but I'm still getting this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you uninstalled the SVN plugins, it would not be possible to get those errors.  You should be able to go to the Team > Synchronize view and remove any SVN related synchronizations.

Finally, whether you want to mainly use TortoiseSVN or not, you should still have Subclipse installed in Eclipse.  Without a SVN plugin installed, Eclipse will do bad things to your working copy.  With Subclipse installed, Eclipse knows to leave the .svn folder alone.

If you are using TortoiseSVN 1.8.x, then be sure to install Subclipse 1.10.x so that you have the right version with Subversion 1.8 support included.